# Excel formula to remove unwanted character

Tags: excel-formula

How to remove unwanted characters on the most right that the back of the word that contain number (from left side) to the right side using Excel formula?
[image: sample word]

I have tried using `Left(cellA, Len(cellA)-7)`. It works fine to fulfill my needs but it also remove some character when the sentence does not contain unwanted.
If using the Find and Replace method will take much time to check line by line and copy to do.

Comment: How do you define what makes a character unwanted or not? What characters are wanted vs which ones aren't?

Comment: I am having problem to use Excel formula to identify the character that I want to remove. Based on the picture above, the word that I want to remove is "KBA0011", "MBB2047" and "KBB3040".

Comment: Will the problem word always be the last word?  Also, do you have Office 365 or an older version?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick  the problem word is always at the end of the sentence. I do not have older Excel version. Does the formula to solve this problem relate to the version of the Excel?

Comment: OK - yes, there are functions in Excel 365 that I would use in this case. It is possible to solve it another way, but the LET function greatly simplifies the formula. I posted it below.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick what is 1,1,1,0,0,0,0 and 0,0,0,1,1,1,1 in line 4 means? 

thanks it works well. Any name for the formula you used? I mean is VBA or any name as it is look complicated and my first time seeing so many function all together and start with LET

Comment: Hi @Azul - the 1,1,1,0,0,0,0 is a mask for the letters. If the first three letters are Capitals between A and Z, the `(w >= "A")*( w <= "Z" )` will produce a pattern of 1,1,1,x,x,x,x. When you multiply that times `1,1,1,0,0,0,0`, it will make the same pattern of `1,1,1,0,0,0,0`. The same is done with the numbers and `0,0,0,1,1,1,1`. When you add these together, they should make `1,1,1,1,1,1,1`. When these are ANDed, they will be TRUE. No - this is a completely invented formula just for your situation, so there is no name. I will call it the AZUL formula. ;-)

Comment: @markfitzpatrick  you have the humor  :)
I still not understand why need to use 1,1,1,0,0,0,0 and 0,0,0,1,1,1,1. Is it a check on whether the starting character of the extracted word from the back is a alphabetic?

Line 1 - identify the cell 
Line 2 - extract the end of the word, total 7 character
Line 3 - CODE will output numerical value, question: what is the purpose of 1 inside the MID?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick  you have the humor  :)
I still not understand why need to use 1,1,1,0,0,0,0 and 0,0,0,1,1,1,1. Is it a check on whether the starting character of the extracted word from the back is a alphabetic?

Line 1 - identify the cell 
Line 2 - extract the end of the word, total 7 character
Line 3 - CODE will output numerical value, question: what is the purpose of 1 inside the MID?
Line 4 - there is a space in front of AND, what is the purpose?

Comment: This may take more space than a comment will allow, so I will put an addendum to the answer that will make it more clear about that the masks are doing and why. As for the MID( lastWord, SEQUENCE(,7),1), it is just breaking lastWord into an array of individual characters of length 1 (that's why it is set to 1). The SEQUENCE(,7) tells MID where to start and 1 tells it how many characters to extract into each of the 7 array elements. As for the space after the AND, that is just formatting to make it more readable. I'm not very consistent with it, but I like spaces so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the problem word will:

- be 7 characters;
- at the end of the string;
- and have the pattern **LLLnnnn** where **L** is a capital letter and **n** is a numerical digit;

with Office 365, you can do:

```
=LET( sentence, B2,
        lastWord, RIGHT( sentence, 7 ),
        w, CODE( MID( lastWord, SEQUENCE(,7),1)),
        IF( AND((w >= 65)*( w <= 90 )*{1,1,1,0,0,0,0} + (w >= 48)*( w <= 57 )*{0,0,0,1,1,1,1} ),
              TRIM( LEFT( sentence, LEN( sentence ) - 7 ) ),
              sentence ) )
```

Where the **sentence** is in B2.

[image]

**Another Approach**
I just realized it could have been a little simpler:

```
=LET( sentence, B2,
        lastWord, RIGHT( sentence, 7 ),
        w, MID( lastWord, SEQUENCE(,7),1),
        IF( AND((w >= "A")*( w <= "Z" )*{1,1,1,0,0,0,0} + (w >="0")*( w <= "9" )*{0,0,0,1,1,1,1} ),
              TRIM( LEFT( sentence, LEN( sentence ) - 7 ) ),
              sentence ) )
```

**How it works** *(in response to the comments)*

The formula first breaks the last 7 characters into a 7 element array of characters using:

`MID( lastWord, SEQUENCE(,7),1)`

So, "ABC0123" becomes an array of:
[image]

Then each character is tested to see if it is a capital letter with this part: `( w >= "A")*( w <= "Z" )`
which produces an array of 1's and 0's through boolean arithmetic.
[image]
You can see that the first three characters were indeed capital letters and the last four were not. But what if we had ABC012A? That would put a 1 in the last array cell. We don't want that one because it needs to be a number.

[image]

There are a number of ways to fix this, but I chose to apply a mask to force it back to zero. I will later test if that character was a number, but for now, I don't want that one in there. When you multiply the mask times the result, it forces the last four cells to zero. Like this:

[image]

> NB: Boolean arithmetic works like this `=TRUE*TRUE` will result in 1
> and `=TRUE*FALSE` results in 0. Multiplying is the same as AND. To OR,
> you  add so that `=TRUE+TRUE` results in 2 (which is the same as
> TRUE), `=TRUE+FALSE` results in 1 and `=FALSE+FALSE` results in 0.

Going back to the original string of ABC0123, if we now apply the number test, you can see the result.

[image]

And when we apply it to ABC012A, we get:

[image]

Now we need to know that both sides are all true. So we can add the arrays to each other. If we just added the arrays together without the masks, it would produce some unintended results. The case of ABC012A would pass because it is adding `1110001` to `0001110` which would be `1111111`. By masking the two sides, we get `1111110` for ABC012A. So the last character failed the test which is what we want.  ABC0123 is adding `1110000` to `0001111` which would be `1111111`. This is what we want. We want all characters to be 1 or TRUE.

So to find that out, we just apply AND to the array.  So here is the end result:
[image]